# Cloud Data Fusion - Write CSV to Google Cloud Storage

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-data-fusion

I am trying to test a simple pipeline in Cloud Data Fusion where I grab data from BigQuery, wrangle the data, then create a file in a Cloud Storage Bucket.

I can not for some reason create the file in cloud storage. No error is presented when running the pipeline preview. The pipeline runs successfully but no file is created.

I can preview the data in all 3 steps so I know I can at least load the data from BigQuery and wrangle it.

Can someone help me in out in how I am supposed to set the properties up to create a CSV in a bucket folder?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3YZOL.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w3Rmx.png)

Tried creating a CSV file in a Google Cloud Bucket using Cloud Data Fusion.

Answer (score 0):

Preview does not write to the target (sinks). The idea behind preview is to validate/debug a pipeline running a small sample from the source and the intent is not to write the iterations to target destinations. Once the preview run is successful, you can deploy and run the pipeline to view the results in the target.

Comment: This was my issue. I did not realize that preview mode does not complete the sink process step. After deploying, the file was sinked successfully. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to transform the data, Dataflow is probably the tool for that. You can export directly into Cloud Storage without Data Fusion or DataFlow. CSV is supported. See:

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/exporting-data#export_formats_and_compression_types

> #### Exporting table data
>
> This page describes how to export or extract data from BigQuery tables
> to Cloud Storage.
>
> After you've loaded your data into BigQuery, you can export the data
> in several formats. BigQuery can export up to 1 GB of data to a single
> file. If you are exporting more than 1 GB of data, you must export
> your data to multiple files. When you export your data to multiple
> files, the size of the files will vary.